# Js- How to restart setInterval after using clearInterval?

Tags: javascript

am using two simple buttons , one for scrolling and the other one for stoping the scroll,

the problem is :

when I reclick on the button of Scrolling after stop scrolling ,

the program
crash suddenly,
and gives me this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')**

the names of imgs are 1 to 6 jpg
for ex : firstphoto name is 1.jpg
so I use **cnt** to crossover them in the code
my code is :

```
  var setBallsMove;
  var cnt=1;
  var getParent=undefined;

document.write("\x3Cbutton onclick='sideShowing()' type='button'> SideShowing !\x3C/button>");
document.write("\x3Cbutton onclick='stop()' type='button'> stop !\x3C/button>");
document.write("\x3Cdiv    class='boy1' > \x3Cimg id=id"+cnt+"     src='SlideShow/1.jpg'  > \x3C/div>");

function sideShowing(){
   
        getParent = document.getElementById("id"+cnt); 
   
         window.setBallsMove=   setInterval(function slid (){     
                window.getParent.src="SlideShow/"+cnt+".jpg";
                getParent.id="id"+cnt;
                cnt++;
            if (cnt==6) {
            cnt=1;}}, 500);
}
function stop(){
 window.clearInterval(setBallsMove); 
 setBallsMove=undefined;
 getParent=undefined;

    };
```

I hope I wrote all info correctly ,thanks for your Pacience

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. You update the `getParent.id` with `cnt` then increment `cnt`. So the `getParent.id` and `cnt` are different next time when you try to `getElementById` and hence you get `null`. You should increment `cnt` before updating `getParent.src` and `getParent.id`.

```
window.setBallsMove = setInterval(function slid() {
    cnt++;
    if (cnt == 6) {
        cnt = 1;
    }
    window.getParent.src = "SlideShow/" + cnt + ".jpg";
    getParent.id = "id" + cnt;

}, 500);
```

But simply speaking, you just don't need to, and shouldn't, change the `id` at all. If you want to store information in an HTML element, use a custom [`data-*`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) attribute.